# How to enable Kaltura Media Gallery for ALL Moodle Courses

Tags: database, moodle, kaltura

I have a Moodle installation with hundreds of courses and modules.
I was tasked with including the Kaltura “Start Meeting” button in each and every module.
Is there a way to accomplish this without having to do it one by one?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEDLl.png)Thanks,
Edgar.

edit adding &strings=1

[adding &strings=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5kHT.png)

Comment: Do you know which version of Moodle / Kaltura this is? Also can you display the source of the string - go to Site administration > Development > Debugging and switch on "Show origin of languages strings" then use `?strings=1` or` `&strings=1` in the url to display the source of the string

Comment: Hello Russell, thanks for the help I use &strings=1 and works but for that area looks like is outside moodle, Kaltura release 4.2.8
Moodle 3.9.4

Comment: Ah yeah, maybe its a frame. I asked about the strings because I couldn't see "live room" in the Moodle code- https://github.com/kaltura/moodle_plugin/blob/4.2.8-3.9/local/kalturamediagallery/lang/en/local_kalturamediagallery.php

Comment: Looks like this is specific to Kaltura not Moodle https://knowledge.kaltura.com/help/enable-newrow-module